# Using find() in loop and creating matrix with results

Tags: matlab

I would like for the results generated with `matchIdx` to be saved to a matrix of separate vectors. This Idx can then be used as addresses in further manipulations.

The issue is when i try assigning to `matchIdx(:,i)` I get errors due to size mismatch of the columns.

I hope somebody can help out. Thank you.

```
data = [1;2;3;3;5;6;6;3;8;8;9;5;6;7;8;9;10];
check = [2;3;5];

for i=1:3
  match(:,i) = ismember(data,check(i));
  matchIdx = find(match(:,i))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear from your question, but I assume you tried

```
matchIdx(:,i) = find(match(:,i));
```

This is not going to work, since `find(match(:,1))` and `find(match(:,2))` are not guaranteed to be the same length.

Would using cell arrays work for you?

```
matchIdx{i} = find(match(:,i));
```

Comment: Yes I did try this. However I was unsure how to use these results in an address. I just found out however!
X = data(matchIdx{2})
I wanted to avoid using associative arrays since i am still a bit noobish..
Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a cell array.  Associative arrays are called `struct` in MatLab, and use the syntax `matchIdx.(key)` IIRC.

Comment: @user1429344 OK, glad to hear you got it working. If the answer helped, feel free to accept it (click on the checkmark) next to it. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple equality instead of ISMEMBER. In one line:

```
>> matchIdx = arrayfun(@(x) find(data==x), check, 'Uniform',false)
matchIdx = 
    [         2]
    [3x1 double]
    [2x1 double]
```